# WSO2 API manager install on AWS instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, amazon-ec2

Steps I done.
After install java runtime and set JAVA_HOME on bashrc.
I deploy the WSO2 API manager on the AWS instance.

Started the service with sh /bin/wso2server.sh

When I am trying to access on the instance with host
host:9443/carbon

I am getting this error on the console.
INFO - StatisticsServiceComponent BAM Service Stat Publishing is disabled
Killed

Please let me know what mistake I done.

[image]

Comment: By default you will get the INFO - StatisticsServiceComponent BAM Service Stat Publishing is disabled
but I never see killed. did you do any config changes? what will happend after the  message?

Comment: I change the bashrc file to change java home. and when I am trying to get the host:9443/publisher I am not able to see anything. And when I check the console I am getting Kill message.

Comment: I dont think it will affect the scenario. I mean did you do any config changes in the wso2 apim?

Comment: No I didn't change anything after deploy the APIM. Just unzip the zip file wso2am-1.9.1.

Comment: it doesnt print anything after that?

Comment: No. Killed the service start.